# I want to create a time slot without overlapping any existing time slots in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi I am new to mongodb trying to creating slots.

Below I have mentioned my model and I have mentioned some queries which are not giving accurate output, here i have some slots previously of a user and when I'm trying create new slots for that user it should not overlaps with any existing time slots.

These are my mongodb sample documents:

```
db={
"teacher": [
{
  "id": 1276,
  "start_time": "2023-03-22T07:00:25.787Z",
  "end_time": "2023-03-22T10:00:35.604Z",
  
},
{
  "id": 1564,
  "start_time": "2023-03-22T07:00:25.787Z",
  "end_time": "2023-03-22T10:00:35.604Z",
  
},
{
  "id": 1276,
  "start_time": "2023-03-22T011:00:25.787Z",
  "end_time": "2023-03-22T15:00:35.604Z",
  
}
]}
```

My query for find out slots already available or not

```
db.teacher.find({
id: 1276,
$or: [
{
  start_time: {
    $gte: new Date("2023-04-22T07:30:00.000Z"),
    $lt: new Date("2023-04-26T13:00:00.000Z")
  },
  
},
{
  end_time: {
    $gt: new Date("2023-04-22T07:30:00.000Z"),
    $lte: new Date("2023-04-26T13:00:00.000Z")
  }
},

]
})
```

this is my desired output if a user passing

```
start_time=2023-03-22T07:30:25.787Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T12:30:25.787Z
Message=slots already available.

start_time=2023-03-22T10:30:25.787Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T11:30:25.787Z
Message=slots already available.

start_time=2023-03-22T06:30:25.787Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T16:30:25.787Z
Message=slots already available.

start_time=2023-03-22T08:30:25.787Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T09:30:25.787Z
Message=slots already available.

start_time=2023-03-22T10:00:35.604Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T011:00:24.787Z
Message=slots not available. now you can create a slot
```

Comment: Why did you leave the ‘Z’ out of your gt query?

Comment: Also, your query has a hardcoded id field.

Comment: @StevenSpungin this is not the real data of my database. it a copy of it.

Comment: You fixed the Z issue, now take out the `id` from the `find` query.

Comment: @StevenSpungin id is required in this place, we will first search according to ID after that we will see its time slots.

Comment: Have you tried `ISODate`

Comment: yes i have tried. i only need that query @StevenSpungin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 possible intersections when checking if timeslot A overlaps timeslot B:

1. A starts before B and ends after B
2. A starts before B and ends during B
3. A starts and ends during B
4. A starts during B and ends after B

Criteria for each of these:

Case 1)

- start time A <  start time B (also implies start time A < end time B)
- end time A > end time B (also implies end time A > start time B)

Case 2)

- start time A <  start time B (also implies start time A < end time B)
- end time A > start time B

Case 3)

- start time A > start time B
- start time A < end time B
- end time A > start time B
- end time A < end time B

Case 4)

- start time A > start time B
- start time A < end time B
- end time A > end time B (also implies end time A > start time B)

These can logically be distilled down to 2 checks:

1. start time A < end time B
2. end time A > start time B

If both of these are true, there is an overlap, otherwise there is no overlap.

```
db.teacher.find({
  id: 1276,
  $and: [
     {start_time: {$lt:"2023-03-22T12:30:25.787Z"}},
     {end_time: {$gt: "2023-03-22T07:30:25.787Z"}}
  ]
})
```

Example with overlap: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kzmlDeiHT4U)
Example with no overlap: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4R4flQXBndH)

If you want a document returned even when there is no overlap, you might try with an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.teacher.aggregate([
  {$match: {id: 1276}},
  {$addFields: {
      overlap: {$and: [
          {$lt: ["$start_time","2023-03-22T011:00:24.787Z"]},
          {$gt: ["$end_time","2023-03-22T10:00:35.604Z"]}
      ]}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$id",
      overlap: {$push: "$overlap"}
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      overlap: {$in: [true,"$overlap"]}
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O3A698l0e2N)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, I appreciate it.  I have checked it, it's working fine for some conditions. but when I'm trying to create  slots that will cover two existing slots, in that case, it should show true but it showing false

Comment: start_time=2023-03-22T06:30:25.787Z,
end_time=2023-03-22T16:30:25.787Z
if we will take the above start time and end time, it's covering the existing two slots, but it showing false

Comment: It returns true when I try those timestamps: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NXrXudxlpir