MongoDB mongoose Find Calendar Conflicts
I have model of Schedule
const scheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    group:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true,
        ref: "Group"
    },
    finalCourse:{
        teacher:{
          type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required:true,
          ref: "Teacher"
         },
    },
    extTeacher:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Teacher"
    },
    fromDate:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    toDate:{
        type:Date,
    },
    fromHour:{
        type:{
            hour:Number,
            minutes: Number
        },
    },
    toHour:{
        type:{
            hour:Number,
            minutes: Number
        },
    },
    fromHourInt:{
        type:Number
    },
    toHourInt:{
        type:Number
    },
    allDay:{
        type:Boolean
    },
    room:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Room"
    }
})

I want to find the conflicts between schedules
The conflict can be if the teacher is in same time in both schedules
for example teacher1 at 04/06/2024 12:00-16:00 in group1
and teacher1 at 04/06/2024 14:00-18:00 in group2
The conflict can be if the group is in same time in both schedules
for exmaple group1 at 04/06/2024 12:00-16:00 with teacher1
and group1 at 04/06/2024 12:00-16:00 with teacher2
What is the best way find the conflicts?
This is my current code (LONG.... and NOT COMPLETE sorry)
I'm not looking for solution just know if there is a aggregate query or something like that to resolve it
const generateAllConflicts = async (req,res)=>{
    const {period} = req.body
    //delete all old conflicts
    try{
        //delete all the preivios conflicts
        const deletedAll = await Conflict.deleteMany({period})
        const conflictsArr = []
        const currPeriod = await Period.findById(period).lean()
        if(!currPeriod) ....
        const schedules = await Schedule.find({period}).populate("finalCourse", {teacher:1}).lean()
        const teachers = await Teacher.find().lean()
        let {fromDate, toDate} = currPeriod
        while ( fromDate < toDate ){
            teachers.forEach(teacher=>{
                const teacherId = String(teacher._id)
                const shceduleSameDaySameTeacher =  schedules.filter(s=> isSameDay(s.fromDate, fromDate) && (s.finalCourse?.teacher?.toString() === teacherId || s.extTeacher?.toString() ===teacherId))
                shceduleSameDaySameTeacher.forEach(ssdst=>{
                    const conflictsList = shceduleSameDaySameTeacher.filter(ssdstMap=> ssdst._id !== ssdstMap._id && hasTimeConflict(ssdst, ssdstMap))
                    if(conflictsList.length){
                        const conflictIds = [...conflictsList.map(c=>c._id), ssdst._id]
                        const conflictObj = {
                            period, schedules:conflictIds, conflictType:"Teacher", conflictDate: fromDate, conflictReason:{dt: fromDate, teacher: teacherId, teacherName: teacher.name }
                        }
                        //check if the array does not exists
                        conflictsArr.push(conflictObj)
                    }
                })
            })
            fromDate = addDays(fromDate, 1)
        }
       if(conflictsArr.length){
        const added = await Conflict.insertMany(conflictsArr)
        ...
       }
 
       
    }
    catch(ex){
 ...
    }

}
const hasTimeConflict = (schedule1, schedule2)=>{

    //need handle the all day
    const {fromHourInt: fh1, toHourInt:th1} = schedule1
    const {fromHourInt: fh2, toHourInt:th2} = schedule2
    if(fh1<=fh2 && th1 > fh2) return true
    if(fh1 > fh2 && fh1 <= th2) return true
    return false
}


It looks like some non-trivial business logic implementation here. What have you tried so far and what is the specific issue you are encountering?

Also, I suggest you respond to/acknowledge the previous answers you received to assure the community members that the time and effort they spent are worthwhile.

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76083153/2282634

the post handle just the time conflict this is just one  challenge
